# Error in jsx file mapping : Unable to generate source map (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting error in browser (ReactJS):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello React</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 id="container"></h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/react/react-0.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/react/JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jsx/HelloWorld.jsx")"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I AM GETTING THE FOLLOWING ERROR: (inspect element > console)

```
GET http://localhost:1869/Scripts/jsx/HelloWorld.jsx?map=460A24595CF673D243983590694BCFEE 500 (Unable to generate source map)
```

How to solve ??? Help needed

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are transforming JSX with JSXTransformer on the client-side since you are including the JSXTransformer script. In that case, JSX script tags need to have the attribute `type="text/jsx"`.